# ClockworkMod Recovery pops up during phone turn on

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, reboot, clockworkmod-recovery

When I turn on my Galaxy S2 phone, ClockworkMod Recovery v4.0.0.2 pops up with the list of options,

```
1- reboot system now
2- apply update from sdcard
3- wipe  data/factory reset
4- wipe cache partition
5- install zip from sdcard
6- backup and restore
7- mounts and storage
8- advanced
9- power off
```

I am unable to figure out a way to turn on my phone. I am new to this so can you help in suggesting a way to access my phone? Every time I reboot the same ClockworkMod screen pops up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed it by rooting the phone with a different kernel version. Installing in appropriate kernel was the reason for this problem.

Comment: can you elaborate?